Comparison operator not working as expected in Awk
I have a file in tabular format called emp.txt which has all details for employees.
eno   ename   esal   ecity
1000   a      2000   Pune
2000   b      4000   Nagpur
3000   c      6000   Delhi
5000   d      1000   Hyderabad

Now I am trying to extract information using awk command for employee where esal is 6000.
Wrote the below expression but not getting desired output, any suggestions ?
awk '{if($3="6000") print $0}' emp.txt

Output I got,
eno ename 6000 ecity
1000 a 6000 Pune
2000 b 6000 Nagpur
3000 c 6000 Delhi
5000 d 6000 Hyderabad

Expected output
3000   c      6000   Delhi

Thanks,
Piyush

Please update your subject line to be related to the problem you want help with. "Usage of AWK command" tells future readers nothing about the problem and so makes it almost impossible for anyone with a similar problem to find the answer.

As in most other C-like languages, = is the assignment operator. Use == for comparison.
awk '{if ($3 == "6000") print $0}' emp.txt

Awk scripts are already structured as condition {action} condition {action} ... so it would be simpler to write it as:
awk '$3 == "6000" {print}' foo.txt

Note that $3 == "6000" is a string comparison, so e.g. 6000.0 would be treated as not equal to 6000. To do a numeric comparison, put a number on the other side, e.g. $3 == 6000.
Also, since the default action is to print the current line, you can omit the action block:
awk '$3 == 6000' foo.txt


Or more like, the default action is {print} short for {print $0}. You can have more than one condition without action such as awk '$1 == "x"; $2 == "y"' (which btw is not the same as awk '$1 == "x" || $2 == "y"').

Worth noting that $3 == "6000" is string comparison, while $3 == 6000 is number comparison (which would also return true for 6e+3, and possibly (depending on locale and its radix character) 6000.0 or 6000,0 or 0x1770 (for the latter, in the case of gawk, only under some non-default conditions such as when POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment)).

@kos, yes, thanks, that what I get for rephrasing what I'm writing on the fly

@ilkkachu it doesn't happen only to those who don't edit at all :)
